# statsmodels binary variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statsmodels

Simple question:

Let's say I have a `pandas.dataframe` holding all of the variables that I want to use for some regression. Some of the variables (either the dependent variable or any of the independent variables) are binary and formatted as either numerical (`0/1`) or boolean (`TRUE/FALSE`). When I pass the `X` and `y` to `statsmodels`, will it "understand" that these should be treated as dummy variables or do I have to specify that? And if so how can I tell the model that some variables are dummy?

Comment: If you only have two values you don't need dummy variables

Comment: Thanks! But if I have more than two, do I have to create the dummies manually (e.g. `pd.get_dummies(..., drop_first=True)`)? Or is there an easier way to just tell `statsmodels` to treat some variable as categorical?

Comment: The underlying mathematical model treats continuous/categorical variables in the same way, so you have to convert categorical to dummies manually.

Comment: if you are willing go use `from statsmodels.formula.api import ols` then you can specify formulas like  `formula='Y ~ X+ C(column_with_categorical_variable)'` and it will then treat that column as a categorical giving you N dummies in the regression output

Comment: @ALollz can I do something similar for MLE (e.g. logit models)?

Comment: It does support quite a few of them: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/api.html#statsmodels-formula-api, logit is in there though I haven't personally used it.

Comment: Thanks! Although I'd prefer just passing `X` and `y`, this seems awesome :)